# NodeJS with MariaDB, Cannot read property 'threadId' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, runtime-error, mariadb

I'm quite desperate, because of this annoying error. I can't find any information about that on the internet.

Actually my application works fine, but if I start multiple queries and wait for them with `Promise.all()`, the server crashes. But step by step:

In my index.js, I'm initializing the connection pool with 60 max. connections, and exporting the variable.

```
 const pool = mariadb.createPool(config.mariaDB);
 module.exports.pool = pool
```

Later I'm importing the index file as "app" and using app.pool.query(...) to query my database.

Next, I have a post request `/getUsersGroups`. A User can be a member of multiple groups, so I expect the response to be an array of objects. Each object contains information about the group. Moreover there is a members field inside this object. This field also is an array containing information about the members, so s.th. like that:

```
[
 {
  "groupId": 125758,
  "title": "test",
  "members": [
         {userId: 5, name:Max, }, ...]
  }, ...
 ]
```

Therefore I have a post request, which looks like that. I'm getting all group ids the user is a member. Then for each `groupId`, I call the method `Group.groupInfo.`

This returns a promise, therefore I'm collecting all promises in an array and wait for all of them, before sending the response.

```
router.post("/getUsersGroups", (req, res) => {
 let userId = req.body.userId;
 let result = []
 let promises = []
 Group.getGroupsByUser(userId) // this gets all group ids the user is a member
   .then((item) => {
         let groups = item.map(x => objectParser.parseUnderscoreToCamel(x))
         for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
             let groupId = item[i].groupId
             promises.push( //adding promises
                Group.groupInfo(groupId, userId)
                        .then((item) => {
                            result.push(item)
                        })
                        .catch((err)=>{console.log(err)}))
         }
    })
    .then(() => {
         // waiting for all promises to finish
         return Promise.all(promises)
             .then(() => {
                    res.status(200).json({groups: result})
                })
     })
     .catch((err) => {
             console.log(err)
            }
     })
}
```

So the Promise `Group.groupInfo` looks like this. It first selects the group information and then for each member inside the group it calls another Promise `User.userInfo`. The pattern is the same like in the method above. So I push the Promise to an array and wait for them to finish:

```
module.exports.groupInfo = (groupId, userId)=>{
    let groupInfo = {}
    let promises = []
    return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
        app.pool.query("SELECT*  FROM Groups WHERE group_id=?", [groupId])
            .then((item) =>{
                groupInfo = item[0]
                groupInfo["members"] = [];
                return app.pool.query("SELECT user_id FROM Users_groups WHERE group_id=?", [groupId])
                    .then((item) =>{
                            let members = [] //contains all user ids
                            for(let i=0; i<item.length;i++){                                                    
                                 members.push(item[i].userId)
                            }   
                            members.forEach((memberId)=>{
                                // for each memberID call User.userInfo
                                promises.push(User.userInfo(userId,memberId) 
                                  .then((item)=>{
                                         groupInfo.members.push(item)}))
                                }
                            })
                    })
           })
        .then(()=>{
            // wait for all Promises
            return Promise.all(promises)
        })
        .then(() =>{
            return resolve(groupInfo)
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
            return reject(err)
        })
   }))
}
```

`User.userInfo` itself, makes a query to the Database to collect the information about the user.

If I'm calling this, the server crashes and giving me this error:

```
activeConnections[conn.threadId] = conn;
TypeError: Cannot read property 'threadId' of undefined
at Pool.handleTaskQueue (****\node_modules\mariadb\lib\pool.js:431:30)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)
```

I guess the problem is somehow with the `Promise.all()` right? 
But I cannot find any information about this error. I'm thankful for every hint!

My solution was not to use Promise.all but to call the Promises sequentially, but seems not right to me.

```
return groupsId.reduce((promise, groupId) => {
                return promise.then(() => {
                    return Group.groupInfo(groupId, userId)
                        .then((item)=>{
                            result.push(item)
                            console.log(result)
                        })
                        .catch((err)=>{
                            throw err
                        })
                })
            }, Promise.resolve())
```

I cannot rely on this, as long as I don't understand the error.

Thanks!